# NSFetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles wrong not english letters

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have data base of artists with russian names on russian language.
The following method show correct russian letter

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

but when I want to show index line:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
}
```

Section letters are like this "?" How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need subclass NSFetchedResultsController to override `- (NSString *)sectionIndexTitleForSectionName:(NSString *)sectionName {
    //or get substring
    return sectionName;
}`